# What is better custom training the bert model or use the model with pretrained data?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, nlp-question-answering

I am coding my own models for a time but I saw huggingface and started using it. I wanted to know whether I should use the pretrained model or train model (the same hugging face model) with my own dataset. I am trying to make a question answering model.

I have dataset of 10k-20k questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state-of-the-art approach is to take a pre-trained model that was pre-trained on tasks that are relevant to your problem and fine-tune the model on your dataset.

So assuming you have your dataset in English, you should take a pre-trained model on natural language English. You can then fine-tune it.

This will most likely work better than training from scratch, but you can experiment on your own. You can also load a model without the pre-trained weights in Huggingface.

Comment: so i should use the original weights and fine tune it with my dataset. And yes dataset is in english.

Comment: Yes exactly. Use the pretrained weights and fine-tune it. The idea is that your model starts with weights that already contain some information about the language. This is of course better than starting to learn from randomly initialized weights (from scratch)